# Nullable warning in Blazor in object List and API (controller) calling

Tags: c#, api, blazor, webassembly, nullable

I'm new in Blazor and I'm a little bit confused about warnings and nullable. If I declare a varible like this: `List<Course> result = new List<Course>();`
I get a warning in here: `result = await ClientHttp.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Course>>("api/GetCourses");`

But if I set the variable as nullable: `List<Course>? result = new List<Course>();`
The first warning dissapears but I get a new one: `result.Remove(aux);`

So, I can build with the warnings and I could hide them but I would like to know what is really happening and how control it.

Comment: One things to learn is this: warnings are good, and unhandled exception crashes in development are GREAT.  I would only add a null check or null ignore to get rid of that green squiggly line when I'm VERY SURE I can't ever have a null value-- like if my api is on the same server as my main Blazor page, and always will be for eternity.  If you wave away a warning with an operator too early in development, then you are inviting a debugging session later.  Consider the green squiggle a "TODO: add exception handler here" unless you are 100% confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable is set to be nullable, it may occasionally become null.
You need to check if the result is null before removing an item.
If the result is null, a null exception will be thrown.

result?.Remove(aux);

Answer (score 2):

Because you initialize `result` it is safe to remove the `?` from the declaration:

```
//List<Course>? result = new List<Course>();
  List<Course> result = new List<Course>();
```

and to use the 'null forgiving operator' `!`,  like this:

```cs
//result = await ClientHttp.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Course>>("api/GetCourses");
  result = await ClientHttp.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Course>>("api/GetCourses")!;
```

In the rest of your code you can now use `result.` , without the `?`. Which is the main goal of enabling 'nullable reference types'.

When the Get fails it is up to your error handling, but the code as-is is Ok. I don't even know when (if) GetFromJsonAsync returns null, it will throw in all relevant cases.

Comment: I think the "!" operator is really dangerous.  Too many people will just realize "the warning goes away if I add '!', and then they're back to square 1: having unhandled null exceptions."

Comment: I agree 100%.  My answer to the OP is to leave the warning until you 100% know that you can never have an error-- or take the 10 seconds to write a block to handle the error.

Comment: I edited a little, getting rid of the `?` is essential here.

Comment: After reading all of your comments, it seems the best practice is control the null and/or try-catch. Which is how I work in asp.net, there is no nullable there.